# Possible to use Compile and AMP TOGETHER in Torch 2.0 and IPEX 2.0?

Tags: optimization, pytorch, intel

I want to know is there any methods to use `torch.compile(backend='ipex')` and Auto Mixed Precision together to further boost model inference. My target platform is Intel's 4th Xeon, and I plan to use pytorch 2.0 and intel extension for pytorch (IPEX) 2.0 to enable aforementioned functions.

I've read PyTorch 2.0's introduction to `torch.compile` [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/pytorch-2.0/#user-experience), and I assume torch 2.0 encourages us to use `compile` API. Ipex 2.0 also recommend to use `torch.compile(backend='ipex')` api [here](https://intel.github.io/intel-extension-for-pytorch/cpu/2.0.100+cpu/tutorials/features.html#torch-compile-experimental-new-feature-from-2-0-0), and it introduce AMP [here](https://intel.github.io/intel-extension-for-pytorch/cpu/2.0.100+cpu/tutorials/features/amp.html). But I found them seems to be incompatible. Is there any method to enable them together? I mean we can get a set of compiled optimized kernel under lower precision, to boost model inference further.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution [here](https://intel.github.io/intel-extension-for-pytorch/cpu/2.0.100+cpu/tutorials/examples.html), just add `dtype=torch.bfloat16` to `ipex.compile`